How can I configure a React WebApp to request camera permission only the first time the user accesses the screen?
We are working on a React WebApp that directly accesses the device's camera and is rendered by a WebView within an app using React Native with Expo (https://expo.dev/). The camera works well, but access permission is requested every time we enter the camera screen.
We have already tried the following:
Save the permission status in storage and check it later, but the application still keeps asking for user permission.
async function checkCamera Permission() {
    const permissionAsked = localStorage.getItem('cameraPermissionAsked');
    if (permissionAsked && permissionAsked === 'true') {
        return true;
    }
    const hasPermission = await requestCameraPermissionAndStopStreams();
    if (hasPermission) {
        localStorage.setItem('cameraPermissionAsked', 'true');
    }
    return hasPermission;
}

We are also using the Qr Scanner library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-scanner) as follows:
function initQrScanner() {
    if (!qrCodeScanner && videoRef?.current) {
        const qrScanner = new QrScanner(videoRef.current, (result) => {
            if (result?.data) {
                setNumber(formatNumber(result?.data));
            }
        },{
            preferredCamera: 'environment',
            highlightCodeOutline: true,
            highlightScanRegion: false           
        });
        qrScanner.start().catch(err => {});
        setQrCodeScanner(qrScanner);
    }
}

With just the library code, the camera asks for access permission every time the user opens the app from scratch. For example, if they have already accessed the screen, navigated to another part of the application and are returning to the screen, the camera does not request authorization again.
Does anyone know how I can ask for user permission only the first time?
